# How do I convert html data to json object?

Tags: java, android, html, json

I want to understand from html to JSON Object.

**Could anyone tell me the rules to write it or provide me any tutorial?**

**How do I convert html data to json object?**

I try to download from daily motion using html url.

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
        super.onPostExecute(output);

        html = output;

        imagelist.add(getRegexBack(html, "property=\"og:image\" content=\"([^\"]+)\""));
        desc = getRegexBack(html, "property=\"og:description\" content=\"([^\"]+)\"");

        String sJs = getRegexBack(html , "\"qualities\":((.+?))\\}\\]\\}");

        if(!sJs.isEmpty()){sJs = sJs+"}]}";}

        try {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sJs);

            for(int i=0; i < json.length(); i++){

                for(int o=0; o <  json.getJSONArray(json.names().get(i).toString()).length() ; o++){

                    String VIDEO = json.getJSONArray(json.names().get(i).toString()).getJSONObject(o).getString("url");

                    if(VIDEO.contains(".mp4")){

                        videolist.add(VIDEO);
                    }
                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {e.getStackTrace();
        }

        if(videolist.size() == 0){
            videolist = getRegexBackArray(xmlCharacterConverter(html), "\"(http([^\\s\"]+)?\\.mp4([^\\s\"]+)?)\"");
            for(int v=0; v < videolist.size() ; v++){
                videolist.set(v , videolist.get(v).replace("\\" , ""));
            }
        }

        if(active){
            if(counter != 5){
                counter++;
            }
            mDialogAdvance();
        }else{
            mDialog = true;
        }
    }[
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olfEw.png)

Comment: have you asked the author? why do you tag it both java and javascript? this is java code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As your question stands now it is unclear what you are trying to achieve or what your problem is. Please edit your question to make it easier to understand. First, explain to us what you are trying to do. Second, detail what you have done so far to reach that goal. Third, explain to us where you got stuck and what is causing the problem. The easier it is to understand your question, the faster you will get an answer.